FullWindowOverlay for android
I'm developing an app with React Native and I'm dealing with a screen which combines a Modal and a BottomSheet inside the modal. The only issue I have is that I'm wrapping the sheet content inside a FullWindowOverlay (from react-native-screens) so it always places above the modal, but this component its only available for iOS.
Is there any Android alternative? I've tried many ways like a View with absolute properties, zIndex, wrapping the sheet within a Portal, etc.. but nothing works.
The example is very simple:
<Modal isVisible>

     ...

     <BottomSheetModal ref={bottomSheetModalRef} snapPoints={snapPoints}>
          <View>
             <Text>Hello</Text>
          </View> 
     </BottomSheetModal>
</Modal>

For those who wonder, the modal is from react-native-modal and the bottom sheet from @gorhom/bottom-sheet
Any help is appreciated!

I have the same situation with an identical stack. It works on iOS with FullWindowOverlay but not on Android.
After many hours of investigation, I decided to use the same react-native-modal and display the modal styled as a bottom sheet only from the bottom, because the thing I needed to implement was quite simple and didn't require all the @gorhom/bottom-sheet features.
result
